# Set UITableViewCell height according to the UIImageView or UILabel which has more height iOS SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I am using table view automatic height and have joint the label to the bottom of the table view cell and number of lines set to 0 and that is running fine.

But the problem is that there is an image view as well. If the text of label is of one line then, image view bottom should set to the bottom of the table view cell to avoid cutting of the imageview. Attached is the image of the design.

Can I set it within the storyboard instead of doing it programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the bottom of the imageView constraint to be greater then or equal

Comment: I have set this constraint of the label because if the label height increases, then the constraint should set to the label instead of the image view